# I cannot scrape table data from multiple URLs using a for loop and BeautifulSoup

Tags: beautifulsoup, index-error

I am trying to scrape table data from several URLs. The table I am looking for is specific and I have indexed it when using .find_all with BeautifulSoup. When I execute the script on one URL for example, it works fine and returns the table I am looking for. The problem arises when I use a for loop to scrape tables from multiple URLs and append them into one dataframe.

```
new_table=pd.DataFrame(columns=range(0,10), index=[0])

k=0
for k in range(0, 11200):
    response=requests.get(urls[k])
    htmls=response.text
    soup=BeautifulSoup(htmls, 'html.parser')

    table=soup.find_all("table")[4]
    row_marker=0
    rows=table.find_all("tr")

    for row in rows:
        column_marker=0
        columns=row.find_all("td")

        for column in columns:
            new_table.iat[row_marker, column_marker]=column.get_text()
            column_marker += 1

    row_marker += 1
    k += 1

new_table
```

Error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-132-13c30de3ad5a> in <module>()
      5     soup=BeautifulSoup(htmls, 'html.parser')
      6 
----> 7     table=soup.find_all("table")[4]
      8     row_marker=0
      9     rows=table.find_all("tr")

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: first thing off the bat. You don't need to increment the k with `k += 1`. your `for k in...:` does that. For the error, the reason you're getting that is because there is no table element at the `[4]` index position. I'm not understanding at the moment why you have that there. Try removing that.

Comment: Ok, just saw that you said it worked for a specific table which is why it's indexed. So my guess is that not all your urls follow that exact structure. for some of your urls it's not indexed at 4, and in fact, doesn't even have that, hence the error. without having/knowing which urls your pulling, it might be difficult to see it, but I'm wondering if you'll have to get all the tables from an url, have it look through the tables, and someway be able to identify if it's the table you want, or to skip over to get your output. Are you really trying to loop through 11,000+ urls?

Answer (score 0):

do not set index table directly add check before

```
table = soup.find_all("table")
if len(table) < 5:
    print('no table[4], skip')
    continue
row_marker = 0
rows = table[4].find_all("tr")
```